While loop not printing message on screen
I'm writing a simple loop to prompt a word from the user.
When user enters a word, we print "Hi" on the screen.
When I'm running this code, I'm getting prompted, but I don't see "Hi" being printed.
let name = ""

while (name !== "Quit") {
  name = prompt("Enter a name")
  console.log("Hi " + name)
}


Javascript is single threaded - as your thread is currently "stuck" in a while loop, it doesn't have a chance to update the console.

Just running your code shows you the answer. It loops until you enter  "Quit" at which point it vomits out everything that was entered

@RoryMcCrossan FYI I intentionally left the runnable example out of the question due to the potential of an annoying infinite loop

@j08691 fair - I thought modern browsers showed a 'stop this popup' option when they detected a loop, but it seems not any more

"but I don't see "Hi" being printed" - you are looking in the browser console, right?

@RoryMcCrossan I did too, but perhaps that there are some circumstances where they do, and this just isn't one.

I see the message is logged on the console, my question is do you want the wrong word to be saved? because when "Quit" is eventually entered, all the words not equal to "Quit" are being logged to the console individually

Do this instead:
function getName() {
  let name = prompt("Enter a name");
  console.log("Hi " + name);
  if (name !== "Quit"){
     getName();
  }
}

getName();
    

The while loop does not execute the console.log until after the loop exits, because it can't multitask like that, for example when you enter your name as Quit then it will update the console log.
But if you do a function that calls itself repeatedly whenever you don't enter Quit for the name then it should work. I just tested it myself. Then it will stay in a loop and update the console log at the same time, because it's breaking out of the loop each iteration and then looping again after that. The while-loop does not break until you exit the loop.
And just FYI in case you don't know you need to be looking at the console log to see this message, it's in your F12 Developer Tools on your browser usually.

Note: this might be ok in this case, but this code will eventually give a Maximum call stack size exceeded error.  Better to use setTimeout(getName, 1) to make the recursive call.

See fdomn-m’s comment—this approach is limited by the max recursion depth in JS (which depending on your situation can be quite limiting), and isn’t a good general approach. If you need a conditional loop in JS you need to use either setTimeout or workers, or to move the logic in question to the backend.

FWIW this question delves into a part of JS that is highly nuanced and requires a deep understanding of the JS event loop. This isn’t a question that’s going to have a simple “do this instead” answer while satisfying the SO standard of  explaining the “why” adequately.
